# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making space separator on integer. This is my code

```
if ( $.fn.appear && $.fn.countTo ) {
    $('.counter').appear(function() {
        $('.timer').each(count);
        function count(options) {
            var $this = $(this);
            options = $.extend({}, options || {}, $this.data('countToOptions').replace(/ /g,'') || {});
            $this.countTo(options);
        }
    });
}
```

When I'm execute an integer can display but show **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined**. So how to fix my code?

Comment: How do we execute this ?

Comment: `($this.data('countToOptions') || '').replace(...`

Comment: @mkHun now an error to be `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined using jQuery` can explain to me ?

Comment: @mkHun, _"'toString' of undefined"_ ?

Comment: @WhoAmI, Do you have any markup associated with the `script` ?